# How late can a Squib show magic?

Tags: harry-potter, squib

I was reading [my own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119653/when-is-a-wizard-confirmed-as-a-squib) and was thinking about @JasonBaker's excellent answer. It says that a Squib is considered a Wizard when they show strong accidental magic, and that's what differentiates late bloomers from Squibs, and leads me to my question.

**What is the latest a Squib could show accidental magic?**

Bonus: *What does Hogwarts do if they're older than 11?*

<sub>This is so closely related to the other question I'm not sure it'd be considered a duplicate or not, but it's meant to determine the time frame for wizarding and Squibs. Feel free to VTC if you feel otherwise....</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Rita Skeeter, magic will invariably have manifested by age 7

> *The timing was significant. Ariana was barely seven years old when she
> vanished from sight, and seven is the age by which most experts agree
> that magic will have revealed itself, if present.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Chapter 11</sup></sub>

That being said, Rowling did originally plan to have a character (possibly Petunia Dursley) who manifested magic later than 11. This [character arc](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html) was shelved which makes the existence of "late bloomers" non-canon since we don't see or hear of any of them in any of her writings.

> **Q.** *Will there be, or have there been, any "late blooming" students in the school who come into their magic potential as adults,
> rather than as children? By the way, I loved meeting you, and hearing
> you speak, when you came to Anderson's in Naperville. I can hardly
> wait until you tour again.*
>
> **JKR:** *Ahhh! I loved the event at Anderson's. It was one of my favorites. That is completely true. No, is the answer. **In my books,
> magic almost always shows itself in a person before age 11; however,
> there is a character who does manage in desperate circumstances to do
> magic quite late in life, but that is veryrare in the world I am
> writing about.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Barnes and Noble interview, March 19, 1999](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html#magic)</sup></sub>

Comment: As always, nice response and something I must have sort of glossed over while reading! +1