# Can squibs do any magic at all?

Tags: harry-potter, squib

In reading the Chamber of Secrets, Neville worries he's going to be attacked by Slytherin's monster. He says, "Everybody knows I'm basically a Squib." But Neville can perform some magic, even if he's not good at it yet. So I'm wondering if Squibs can preform a little magic. I know they can see Dementors but can they produce any magic at all? Why would Neville think he's almost a Squib if he can do some magic.

Comment: I'm guessing the idea is like a magical disability, and in that case, it'd vary greatly from person to person, despite the term being used as a catch-all for someone who completely can't.

Comment: "Why would Neville think he's almost a squib if he can do some magic." Because that's how the English language works? If Squibs can do no magic, and Neville can barely do magic, then he's almost (basically) a Squib.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [When is a “Wizard” confirmed as a Squib?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119653/31394)

Comment: A monster is going around attacking children with a specific motive. The boy is made to suffer for his lack of magic by his family. Why wouldn't he be scared of the monster going around punishing those that are not magic enough? Don't read those books as if they were a Wikipedia article. J Rowling writes those books from a truly subjective perspective. Here are many people that don't get that and think everything in there is a fact and are thus confused. Perhaps try thinking about them as a perception or opninion instead for example when you are confused the next time

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per Pottermore's [Everything you need to know about Squibs](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-need-to-know-about-squibs)

> Although like a Muggle **they can’t perform magic.**

Which chimes nicely with Ron's description in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets.

> "*A Squib is someone who was born into a wizarding family **but hasn’t got
>   any magic powers.***"

and [JKR's article on squibs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120208051328/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19) from her original website

> A Squib is almost the opposite of a Muggle-born wizard: **he or she is a
>   non-magical person** born to at least one magical parent. Squibs are
>   rare; magic is a dominant and resilient gene.

---

A squib who can do *some* magic is therefore, by definition, not a squib, just a crap wizard.

Comment: If ibid was here I know what he'd say about your first source.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I'm happy enough with it. It matches what we see in the books and JKRs own description.

Comment: Yes thank you :)

Comment: While squibs don't have magic (as you say), there are social differences between squibs and muggles. As squibs, they have one foot in the wizarding world. As a result (and unlike muggles) they may have access to magic even if they can't cast it. For example, magical animals (like Figg's cats) or potentially enchanted objects created by wizards.

Comment: @Glimmervoid : and squibs are likely not repelled by muggle-repelling charms, and are able to see things (Knight Bus, Hogwarts Express, magical trunks, and even Hogwarts itself) which are invisible or disguised for muggles. Likely they can use magical items even if they can't themselves create or enchant them, while muggles can't, they might not even be able to really perceive them.

Comment: Rowling saying "magic is a dominant gene" is due to her not knowing what the word "dominant" means in biology. Magic is likely recessive, and a magical and non-magical gene make a squib, while two non-magical genes make a muggle. Muggleborns likely have two squib parents, who just don't know about themselves that they are (biologically) squibs. The best proof of this is Hermione, who is muggleborn yet has very strong magic. This hints on magic being carried by a single gene.

Answer (score 0):

No, they can't do any magic.
Reason why Neville said he is almost a squib is that he was highly underestimating himself, plus he had his father's wand which wasn't completely loyal to him - he wasn't able of great magic with that. He turned out to be very gifted wizard later.