# Why do Filch's and Mrs. Figg's Harry Potter Top Trump cards say they are capable of magic?

Tags: harry-potter

Both Filch and Mrs. Figg are Squibs, which means they lack magic power, but were born into wizarding families.

However, their Top Trump cards, specifically the *Order of the Phoenix* ones, rank their magic power at a bit more than 0. Filch's card had his magic ranked at 8, meaning if you put that against [Young Pettigrew's card,](http://cdn.ecommercedns.uk/files/2/229812/6/6966376/document-20190926-0029.jpg) which put his at 1, as to magic power, Filch would win.

[image: Arabella Figg. Mrs. Figg, the Dursleys' elderly neighbour, is more than just the little cat-loving lady next door. After Harry battles Dementors™ in Little Whinging, she reveals that Dumbledore™ had asked her to keep an eye on him - and later testifies on Harry's behalf at his Ministry of Magic™ hearing. Magic: 40. Cunning: 13. Courage: 30. Wisdom: 52. Temper: 4.] [image: Argus Filch. Argus Filch is the caretaker of Hogwarts™ castle. He clearly enjoys disciplining students, and is thus loathed by every student in the school. Magic: 8. Cunning: 16. Courage: 11. Wisdom: 42. Temper: 9.]

Why is this?

Comment: 2005 Specials - https://www.tcdb.com/Images/Cards/Gaming/186948/186948-11848189Fr.jpg gives him a 5

Comment: Just a an aside, the PC game of Philosopher's Stone suggests Filch *can* do magic. He manages to somehow lock a magic door in the library.

Comment: Hmm... this is probably contradicted somewhere in the source material, but I had thought that Squibs were just under some sort of threshold in terms of being able to do magic. It's kind of like how, at one point, there were minimum IQs in the United States to be considered a legal adult.

Comment: I admit I'm surprised at these two magic levels relative to each other (having no idea what a standard wizard's might be on the same scale). I don't think Mrs. Figg is ever shown doing the slightest bit of magic, but I would argue Filch's relationship to his cat Mrs. Norris is definitely magical.

Comment: @WolfieSmith - Possibly worth its own question, but I believe he's commanding *a magic door* to lock, rather than using magic on it himself.

Comment: What are the ranges of these numbers?  8 is obviously a lot lower than 40, but what numbers would you see on more obviously powerful wizards?  Hard to say how appropriate these numbers are without knowing that.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFZW.png It's all pretty inconsistent. It ranges from zero (Petunia Dursley) to 113 (Dumbledore and Voldemort). Neville and Luna are both rated lower than Arabella Figg

Comment: @Valorum From your image... "Bumbledore"?  "Lovergood"?  I think this source may be somewhat unreliable if they can't even spell major characters' names right...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - lol. That was me checking if anyone was paying attention

Answer (score 3):

The [blurb](https://winningmoves.co.uk/products/harry-potter-and-the-half-blood-prince-top-trumps) for the cards state that the ranking is based on the **possession of magic**, not necessarily the capacity to use it. Squibs are clearly *magical [in some respects](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188357/can-squibs-do-any-magic-at-all)* but their low levels of power make it impossible for them to use active magic. Low isn't zero.

> Pit your favourite characters against each other to **find out who
> really possesses the most magic** or is the most cunning.

This chimes nicely with Ron's description of a squib;

> *"A Squib is someone who was born into a wizarding family but hasn’t got any magic **powers**."*

Comment: If it's based on "possession of magic" perhaps it covers not just their own magical powers, but also potential magical artefacts, allies or creatures they could call upon. Despite having no magic himself, Filch might be able to rely on some of the innate magics within Hogwarts, for instance.

Comment: @Showsni - Plus he operates things like a sneakoscope and has a KwikSpell coursebook. It's possible that he *knows* a reasonable amount of magic, just that he can't perform it

Comment: As a simple example, Filch has the aid of a magic cat!

Comment: Indeed, although it's not explicitly explained in canon, it seems to be a pretty widespread fan theory that the difference between Wizards and Squibs is that Squibs can't cast spells, and the difference between Squibs and Muggles is that Muggles can't use magic artifacts, potions, etc, and often can't see magic at all. For example, the Knight bus, the Hogwarts Express, magical trunks (and Hogwarts itself), are likely invisible (or disguised) to Muggles but visible to Squibs. So Squibs cannot cast spells but can interact with magic, and can use magic through magical items, while Muggles cannot.